# How to mulitiply two arrays of different shape in numpy to get a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have for example two arrays, a and b. Array a has a length of 3. Array b an arbitrary length.

I would like to do the following with a numpy approach:

```
temp_res = 0    
for i in range(3):
    tem_res += a[i] * b
```

*a* can be treated as a vector of scalar values for multiplication. Basically I want to have a Matrix with 3 rows which has the same length as *b* and are multiplied with *a*'s value at the corresponding index. However, because of the different shapes, I do not say any how to this without any loop (or list comprehension).

How can the example above implemented with purely numpy (and without any python loop)? I already checked out the documentation, but same shape is always a condition.

Comment: From the `absolute basics` documentation, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html#broadcasting

Comment: There is also a `np.outer` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to read about [numpy broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html), putting 1 in the first dimension of b will force broadcasting on it, a reshape only changes the stride but doesn't make a copy of the data.

```py
tem_res = a * b.reshape([1,-1])
```

this can also be written this way in case b was larger than 2D

```py
tem_res = a * b[None,:]
```

Example:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.ones([3,4])  # 3x4 array of ones
b = np.zeros([4])  # 1D array 4 elements of zeros
c = a * b.reshape([1,-1])  # b.reshape is now 1x4, it can be multipled by 3x4
print(c)  # confirm it is 3x4 array
```

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```